# NSRegularExpression error, I can't use Regular Expressions

Tags: ios, regex, swift, swift2, nsregularexpression

I was creating a Regular expression but in can´t solve this problem

```
class Regex {
    let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression
    let pattern: String

    init(_ pattern: String) {
        self.pattern = pattern
        var error: NSError?
        self.internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
    }

    func test(input: String) -> Bool {
        let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, countElements(input)))
        return matches.count > 0
    }
}
```

Here are the errors I got:

> "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSRegularExpression' with an argument list of type '(pattern: String, options: _, error: inout NSError?)'"

and

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'countElements'"

I only want to use this:

```
if usuarioView.text! =~ "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,30}$/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.  It looks like you are migrating from an earlier version of Swift to Swift 2.x.

The `NSRegularExpression` initializer has changed to throw its error instead of passing in an `ErrorPointer`:

```
do {
    self.internalExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

To specific `nil` for an `OptionType` value, use `[]`.  To get the length of a string, use `input.characters.count`, since `countElements` has been removed from Swift:

```
let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: [], range:NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))
```